# Error: Cannot find module 'node:util' while running the nuxt project using npm run command

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, node-modules, package.json

I created a new nuxt 2 project using the following commands

`npm init nuxt-app <project-name>`

after the `npm install` command when i try to run it using `npm run dev` it throws the follwing error (attached image)

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
> throw err;
>
> > ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'node:util'
> Require stack:

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

node version : v14.16.1
npm version : 6.14.12
nuxt version: 2.15.8

i've tried the following:

1. deleting node_modules and package-lock
   npm cache clean --force
   npm i
   npm ci
   npm run dev
2. installing nuxt utils

none of these work

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLB25.png)

Comment: Did you update your node version?

Comment: @miltonbhowmick i updated it to 16.10.0, still throws the same error.

Comment: FIxed the error by changing the nuxt version in package.json to **"2.15.8"** (removed the **^** , which was upgrading the dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by @r-rodrigues changing `the nuxt version in package.json to "2.15.8" and removed the ^ (caret symbol) , which was upgrading the dependencies`